# jQuery won't correctly POST a JSON containing an array as one of its properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to use jQuery to send a JSON object, which has an array as one of its properties, to my API endpoint. I've defined it like this:

```
let bidding = {
  "name": $("#name").val(),
  "applicant": $("#applicant").val(),
  "start_date": $("#start_date").val(),
  "end_date": $("#end_date").val(),
  "products": []
}

$("#products").children(".dropdown").each(function(key, value) {
  bidding.products.push(
    {
    "product_name": $(value).children(".btn").text(),
    "quantity": $(value).children("input").val()
    }
  );
});
```

And when I do a `console.log(JSON.stringfy(bidding))` it parses just as expected, for example:

```
{
  "name":"Material de Construção",
  "applicant":"Prefeitura",
  "start_date":"26/09/2017",
  "end_date":"01/10/2017",
  "products":[
    {"product_name":"Cimento (5kg)","quantity":"200"},
    {"product_name":"Tijolo","quantity":"100"},
    {"product_name":"Caneta","quantity":"5"}
  ]
}
```

But when I POST it using `$.post("/api", bidding);` my API receives it like this:

```
{
  name: 'Material de Construção',
  applicant: 'Prefeitura',
  start_date: '26/09/2017',
  end_date: '01/10/2017',
  'products[0][product_name]': 'Cimento (5kg)',
  'products[0][quantity]': '200',
  'products[1][product_name]': 'Tijolo',
  'products[1][quantity]': '100',
  'products[2][product_name]': 'Caneta',
  'products[2][quantity]': '5'
}
```

How can I make it so jQuery will stop creating new properties for each entry in the array and instead send the entire array as a single property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set to false:

> [processData](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Hence your post will be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api",
    data: JSON.stringify(bidding),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, so I went ahead and replaced my "$.post("/api", bidding);" with "$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "/api", data: JSON.stringify(bidding), processData: false, contentType: "application/json", dataType:"json", success: function () {} });" and that did it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("/api", JSON.stringify(bidding));
```

And in the server side decode the json. If you are using php use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Using json is always a good idea to preserve the data structure

Comment: I did attempt that, but it ended up being too much trouble since I'm using Express/Node.js with BodyParser and BodyParser was parsing the string wrong.